# Decrease spacing in text nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics

I have some nodes that only contain text. As far as I know, I need to use nodes to write simple text in `tikz`. The problem is, that the spacing between words is way too large for my taste (it is definitely not the normal spacing in all other parts of my document/graphs). Can this be fixed somehow?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=6cm] at (0,1) {\tiny \parbox{4cm}{1. Distance between words too large}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\node[text width=6cm] at (0,1) {\tiny\spaceskip=2pt \parbox{4cm}{1. Distance between words too large}};`, i.e. add `\spaceskip=2pt` (say), or, better `\node[text width=6cm,font=\tiny] at (0,1) {\parbox{4cm}{1. Distance between words too large}};`, i.e. say `font=\tiny`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason tikz does make the spaceskip by default so large? Can I set this globally to something more reasonable (for tikz only)?

Comment: No, you just did not use the intended way of making the font tiny: use the `font=\tiny` key.

Comment: I see that is it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to make the font tiny is to use `font=\tiny` (rather than just adding `\tiny` in the node). (You could also customize your `\spaceskip`.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,1) node[right,text width=6cm]  {\tiny \parbox{4cm}{1. Distance between words too large}}
    node[left,font=\sffamily]{original:}
     (0,0)  node[right,text width=6cm,font=\tiny] {\parbox{4cm}{2. Distance between words too large}}
    node[left,font=\sffamily]{use the \texttt{font=\textbackslash tiny} key:}    
      (0,-1) node[right,text width=6cm]  {\tiny\spaceskip=2pt \parbox{4cm}{3. Distance between words too large}}
    node[left,font=\sffamily]{using \texttt{\textbackslash spaceskip}:};      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]